# How to notify to System Administrator when questions asked in Web Chat which does not exists in the answer DB

Tags: bots, botframework

I built a Q and A system using QnA Maker that provide Web Chat via Bot Service.
Is there a way to notify the the question contents to the system administrator when question with no answer is made?

Comment: are you using c# or node?

Answer (score 0):

The QnA Maker service will return “no match found” it it couldn’t match anything. What happens then depends on how you want to handle it in your specific scenario.

For more information on integrating QnA Maker service with your bot, check out:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure/azure-bot-service-template-question-and-answer

Example QnA Maker Dialog:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/QnAMaker

Comment: Thank you for answering my question Nils.
I just wanted to know whether the Log of "no match find"'s question be made
and if the log will made, what directory to look up for the Log file.
I hope I can look up for the "no match find"'s question of QnA Maker.

Answer (score 0):

The `QnAMakerDialog` and the `Train API` together provide a feature called `Active Learning` that supports functionality similar to what you're looking for.  Please see https://qnamaker.ai/Documentation/ActiveLearning

Here is an excerpt from the current doc:

> Learning new QnAs
>
> Once enough unique users give similar feedback, the
>   service automatically adds a new learnt QnA pair to the KB. The bot
>   developer can still review and edit these learnt QnAs before
>   publishing to production.
>
> To safeguard against fraud feedback, the system requires that similar
>   feedback has been provided by a bunch of unique users (identified by
>   userid in the Train API).
>
> The active learning process kicks in after every 50 feedbacks sent to
>   the service via the Train API.
>
> In both the above cases, the learnt QnAs and the alterations need to
>   be published explicitly by the developer, to impact the production
>   endpoint. This step gives you a change to review the active learning
>   changes before impacting your users.

There is also a sample that demonstrates `QnA Active Learning` : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/QnAMaker#qna-bot-with-active-learning